# Health issues concerning video lights

Tags: lighting

For a small home studio lighting setup, I have concluded that softboxes with clf bulbs or LED panels would be adequate.

But clf bulbs contain mercury, and even though it is a small amount, accidents tent to happen.

On the other hand, I have read that LED lights are bad for eyes. I don't conclude related links because I think that you all have heard of that. If so, does the quality of the bulb has to do something with that? That is because I intend to buy some Chinese ones, I can't afford anything else.

Are all these issues real or myth? Any thoughts or alternative suggestions would be appreciated.

P.S. I am interested in 5600K bulbs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mercury is enclosed within the bulb, and does not pose any threat to the user, unless the bulb breaks. In such case the amount of mercury released is still rather small, though it certainly makes sure to clean it properly. More important is safe disposal of the bulbs. See e.g. this article: https://earth911.com/home-garden/broken-cfl-clean-up/

LEDs can be tiring for eyes due to flickering. LEDs for photography should not flicker much, otherwise they will produce visible artifacts.